# Specifying correlations among random effects in brms package in R

Tags: r, bayesian, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

For this example, I am using the data "appendix_example1_wide.SUPP.FINAL.csv" posted [here](http://supp.apa.org/psycarticles/supplemental/a0035628/a0035628_supp.html).

In the paper, the authors use the to [MCMCglmm package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/index.html) fit a multivariate multilevel model. Of particular interest, they use the following code to estimate covariances between random effects (e.g., random intercepts from each outcome):

```
prior1 <- list(R = list(V = .2*diag(2), nu = 3),
               G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(c(.2,.2,.1,.1)), nu = 5)))

mult.mcmc <- MCMCglmm(
  cbind(y1, y2) ~ -1 + trait + trait:tx + trait:time + 
  trait:time:tx,
  data = data1,
  random = ~ us(-1 + trait + trait:time):pid,
  rcov = ~ us(trait):units,
  family = c("gaussian","gaussian"),
  nitt = 25000, burnin = 5000, 
  prior = prior1
)
summary(mult.mcmc)
```

Is it possible to specify the same model using the [brms package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html)? Here's my attempt (that did not even closely reproduce the estimates from the paper):

```
mod1 <- brm(cbind(y1,y2) ~ 1 + time*tx + (1 + time|pid),data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was missing a small piece of code. This code does the trick by specifying the covariances between the random effects:

```
 mod1 <- brm(cbind(y1,y2) ~ 1 + time*tx + (1 + time|p|pid), 
        data=data)
```